# How to embbed a haxe application in a flex mobile application?

Tags: android, apache-flex, haxe

Is it possible to embbed a haxe application in an flex mobile application?

Thing is, I need to record videos locally and I would like to use a lightweight media server that is written in haxe. So it would be awsome if, I could embbed it in my application?
I can't really see a way of doing it, but I am considering native extensions, and such...

Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Could you provide a link to that "media server, written in Haxe"?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/